# When to use each of the three double-angle identities for cosine?

Tags: trigonometry

There are three double angle identities that are all equivalent to each other. The concept of the equations being equivalent sounds fair to me, except I noticed each one has a specific time when to be used precisely with the problem.

> How will I know when one of the three should be used according to the question?

I noticed it does matter at times, but maybe I do not understand the concept as a whole, does anyone know which instances I should choose either, other, or? Perhaps I am mistaken, but if so, could someone clarify why?

Thank you

Comment: Well, it depends on the question.

Comment: You may want to use one form over the other if you have to write your expression solely in terms of $\sin\theta$, for example.

Comment: @Doubtnut Ah okay, thank you. I wanted to make sure.

Comment: @AndrewChin Thank you, this makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the problem:

> Solve the equation $$\cos2\theta=\cos\theta.$$

Recognizing that $$\cos2\theta=\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1=1-2\sin^2\theta,$$ which form do you feel is appropriate?  Since the right side of the equation is written in terms of $\cos\theta$, perhaps it is most useful to write $\cos2\theta$ in terms of $\cos\theta$ as well:
\begin{align}
\cos2\theta&=\cos\theta\\
2\cos^2\theta-1-\cos\theta&=0\\
(2\cos\theta+1)(\cos\theta-1)&=0
\end{align}
This way, you can solve the quadratic equation in terms of $\cos\theta$.

---

Another example where the choice is relevant:

> Simplify the expression $$\frac{\cos2\theta}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}.$$

We would have $$\frac{\cos2\theta}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}=\frac{\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}=\frac{(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}=\cos\theta-\sin\theta.$$